# Google Analytics: no recent data within Multi-Channel Funnel

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Data within the Multi-Cahnnel Funnel in Google Analytics are missing for today and yesterday. Data for the previous days are available. Is there a lag for the data to appear?

Comment: It takes 24 to 48 hours for Google analytics to process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data will be showed if there is at least one conversion and after up to 48 Hrs.If you would like to check whenever or not to expect data flowing check your current conversions in another report.

Also, make sure you have setup your funnels in a view without filters. If you apply filters incorrectly this could be one of the causes why you are not seeing the data